# Scope issues in android Development

Tags: java, android, class, scope

So I'm familiar with OOP and java basics.

Some of the nuances of Android still escape me though.

I am having a real issue with the scope of some of my classes right now. Here's an example:

In my activity, I reference a custom class called "Player" a player can do a number of thing including draw tiles, and place tiles.

I'm keeping a list of all undrawn, available tiles in an array of AVAILABLE_TILES in my activity. This is important because I reference that list all the time in many different situations.

Here's my issue though.

Here's the code in my activity:

```
    public void setUpPlayers(){
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        players[i] = new Player(playerNames[i], 6000);
        players[i].drawTile(1); //draw one tile

        //find the ID for the tile just placed
        String tileID = players[i].findTileIdByIndex(0); //first tile in thier tile pool

        players.[i].placeTile(tileID);          

        Log.d(players[i].getName(), tileID);
    }
}
```

and here's the code from the "Player" class:

```
    public void drawTile(int quantity){

    //repeat for the total number of tiles being drawn
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {

        //get a random tile ID from the list of available tiles
        int randomTileIndex = RNG.nextInt(AVAILABLE_TILES.size());
        String randomTileName = AVAILABLE_TILES.get(randomTileIndex);

        //add this tile to the player's pool of tiles
        addPlayerTile(randomTileName);

        Log.d("AVAILABLE_TILE_REMOVED", String.valueOf(randomTileIndex));

        //and remove that tile now from the available tiles list
        AVAILABLE_TILES.remove(randomTileIndex);            
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I've got an ArrayList that holds the ID of every available tile. (Not in any player pool, and not on the board.)

The issue is, that since that **ArrayList** is in the activity, I can't seem to reference it in Player.java.

Do I need to import some android related library to Player.java?

In another situation, I've made an array of a custom class "Tile" that extends Button, and that has no problems with referencing the global (Static) variables in the activity.

So What's the solution?

Thank you in advance for your help,

JRad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out now.

I needed to reference the array in a "static way". Meaning the following format:

[ClassNameTheHoldsTheArray].ArrayName

So in this instance, I had to use the reference GameBoardActivity.AVAILABLE_TILES

Thanks for everyone's help.

JRad

Comment: Stack Overflow says I must wait 2 days before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

visibility of AVAILABLE_TILES in Activity probably is your issue

Comment: care to elaborate? AVAILABLE_TILES is set to **public static**

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Player` constructor to take as parameter a reference to your activity. In the constructor set a variable of your activity class' type (e.g. `MyActivity mActivity`) that is defined in your `Player` class equal to this parameter. Now, whenever you need to access `AVAILABLE_TILES`, access it via `mActivity.AVAILABLE_TILES`.

**EDIT**
The above assumed `AVAILABLE_TILES` is not static. If it is, simply qualify it properly, e.g. `MyClass.AVAILABLE_TILES`.